# Mock an object in a method that is not a parameter in java similar to the following python code?

Tags: java, python, junit, mocking, python-unittest

following is a very cool mocking with python, is there anyway to do that also in java?

```
mockpath = os.path
mockpath.isdir = Mock(return_value=False)
myObj = MyClass()
myObj.invoke_some_method()
myObj.some_other_method.assert_called_with(False)
```

is anything like this possible in java? meaning updating the return values and behavior of objects instantiated inside other object methods in such a convenient way? any framework to do that so nicely?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that powermock library is the most suitable for this in java and most resembels mocks.py

Answer (score 1):

Mockito supports [partial mocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16) as well as [mocking out a method in a real class](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13). The latter looks more similar to your Python example.

I believe EasyMock supports the same thing but I'm having trouble finding where it is in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, I looked at mockito however i didn't notice I can also mock multiple objects used in a method is it possible with it? in example I have methodA which calls new obj1, new obj2 and then obj1.doA and obj2.doB will I be able from outside with mockito to have that method call my own obj1Mock and obj2Mock which would be defined from within my test method

Comment: If your class under test calls `new Object1()` itself, then I don't believe any mocking library can swap that out, unless it manipulates the byte code of `Object1` at runtime. Instead, use dependency injection to pass the instances of `Object1` and `Object2` to the class under test.